# Understanding with statement to catch ValueError in unittest class

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest, with-statement

New to unittest and Python in general, came across example in a tutorial introduction to unit testing wherein a with statement is used to catch a ValueError.

The script being tested (invoice_calculator.py) is:

```
def divide_pay(amount, staff_hours):
    """
    Divide an invoice evenly amongst staff depending on how many hours they
    worked on a project
    """
    total_hours = 0
    for person in staff_hours:
        total_hours += staff_hours[person]

    if total_hours == 0:
        raise ValueError("No hours entered")

    per_hour = amount / total_hours

    staff_pay = {}
    for person in staff_hours:
        pay = staff_hours[person] * per_hour
        staff_pay[person] = pay

    return staff_pay
```

The unit test includes this function in order to catch an edge case wherein `staff_hours = None` :

```
import unittest
from invoice_calculator import divide_pay

class InvoiceCalculatorTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_equality(self):
        pay = divide_pay(300.0, {"Alice": 3.0, "Bob": 6.0, "Carol": 0.0})
        self.assertEqual(pay, {'Bob': 75.0, 'Alice': 75.0, 'Carol': 150.0})

    def test_zero_hours_total(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            pay = divide_pay(360.0, {"Alice": 0.0, "Bob": 0.0, "Carol": 0.0})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Regarding the use of the `with` statement in `test_zero_hours_total(self)`, what is actually happening here in terms of how this statement works/is being executed?

Is the `test_zero_hours_total()` function basically working as follows (layman's description): the expected error should be `ValueError` (which we're doing by passing `ValueError` to the function `assertRaises()`) when `360.0, {"Alice": 0.0, "Bob": 0.0, "Carol": 0.0}` (which would raise a `ValueError` in `divide_pay()`) is passed as arguments to the `divide_pay()` function?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your question is here ...

`TestCase.assertRaises` creates an object that can be used as a context manager (which is why it can be used with the `with` statement).  When used this way:

```
with self.assertRaises(SomeExceptionClass):
    # code
```

The context manager's `__exit__` method will check the exception information passed in.  If it is missing, an `AssertionError` will be thrown causing the test to fail.  If the exception is the wrong type (e.g. not an instance of `SomeExceptionClass`), an `AssertionError` will be thrown as well.

Comment: My question is: is my understanding of how the with statement in the unit test works basically correct?

Comment: @Malvin9000 -- I think so?  Does your understanding match with the description I just wrote?  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you understand what the test is doing. You might find it useful to see how you could write the test if `assertRaises` did not exist.

```
def test_zero_hours_total(self):
    try:
        pay = divide_pay(360.0, {"Alice": 0.0, "Bob": 0.0, "Carol": 0.0})
    except ValueError:
        # The exception was raised as expected
        pass
    else:
        # If we get here, then the ValueError was not raised
        # raise an exception so that the test fails
        raise AssertionError("ValueError was not raised")
```

Note that you don't have to use `assertRaises` as a context manager. You can also pass it the exception, a callable, and arguments for that callable:

```
def test_zero_hours_total(self):
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, divide_pay, 360.0, {"Alice": 0.0, "Bob": 0.0, "Carol": 0.0})
```

Comment: And with the help of `contextlib`, this form of `assertRaises` becomes pretty easy to write.

Comment: @mgilson I've not used contextlib before, I'll have to give that a go :)

Comment: This would be a fun toy problem to get yourself used to it.

Answer (score 0):

should it be:
self.assertEqual(pay, {'Bob': 100.0, 'Alice': 200.0, 'Carol': 0.0})

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34619755)

Comment: @rob: Can you explain why this _isn’t_ an answer to the question? It looks like one to me. Am I missing something?